# Csutom Nuget Package Creation

Tags: .net, nuget, asp.net-core-2.0

Recently, I created the nuget package and referred it in my another project .
And it worked fine.

For now, I switched to another pc and resume to work.
Source code of  is in github, so I cloned the latest commit.
But I can't see that it is working.

Actually, methods in my custom nuget are using http request to another api.

For now, if I call the nuget method, it prints the consoles before calling the api request inside nuget method.
But fails after this (inside nuget mothod).

I thought that api was broken and checked it but it is not changed and still working if I create the test project that is using this api.

So, I think api call is not working correctly in my custom nuget methods.

Problem is that my old pc is still working with this nuget package.
Hope someone help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: can you show the code?

Comment: Yes, I can show it. But it is working in test project if I create new one. 
And also working in my old pc.

I think there may be some setting issue

Comment: Hi, @Alexan, do you still want to see the code?

Comment: I just want to say there isn't enough information to help you with this problem

Comment: Hi, @Alexan, sorry for late response, 
There was my mistake to generate the api root url inside the nuget method.